# Django Rest Framework: allow a serializer field to be created, but not edited

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

Right now, DRF's `read_only` argument on a `Serializer` constructor means you can neither create nor update the field, while the `write_only` argument on a `Serializer` constructor allows the field to be created OR updated, but prevents the field from being output when serializing the representation.

Is there any (elegant) way to have a `Serializer` field that can be created, exactly once, when the model in question is created (when the `create()` is called on the `Serializer`), but cannot that later be modified via `update`?

**NB**: Yes, I've seen [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40186266/django-rest-framework-create-only-serializer-field), but honestly I find it ugly and un-Pythonic. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
class TodoModifySerializer(ModelSerializer):

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        data = super(TodoModifySerializer, self).to_internal_value(data)
        if self.instance:
            # update
            for x in self.create_only_fields:
                data.pop(x)
        return data

    class Meta:
        model = Todo
        fields = ('id', 'category', 'title', 'content')
        create_only_fields = ('title',)
```

you can do it in `to_internal_value` method by remove this data when update

Comment: Raising an error would be better, if not the client won't know why the data is just disappearing.

Answer (score 4):

By "not elegant", I'm assuming you only want one serializer for both creates and updates. You could perhaps consider overriding the [`update`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/) method of your serializer and remove the `create_only_field` from `validated_data` before saving:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        validated_data.pop('create_only_field')
        return super().update(instance, validated_data)

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('id', 'field_one', 'field_two', 'create_only_field')
```

You would, however, have to supply the old (or some) field value when updating your model.

Comment: You could just keep the instance value in the validation, or return a validation error

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any, you either specify it like that or make your own serializer, inheriting from DRF's serializer.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the field REQUIRED and read-only on update I've handled it on field validation.

```
class MyUserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    username = serializers.CharField(source='user.username', required=True)
    first_name = serializers.CharField(source='user.first_name')
    last_name = serializers.CharField(source='user.last_name')

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ['user', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'phone']
    
        read_only_fields = []

    def validate_username(self, value):
        if not self.instance and not value:      ## Creation and value not provided
            raise serializers.ValidationError('The username is required on user profile creation.')
        elif value and self.instance != value:   ## Update and value differs from existing
            raise serializers.ValidationError('The username cannot be modified.') 
    return value
```

You can also make the field optional in case of edition, but you need to set the field as required=False and do validation in validate() method, since validate_username() wouldn't be called in creation if not included in the payload.